# Grab key and value in .map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Not sure what I'm missing here:

```
export function extractOptions(options){
  return options.map((option, i) => {
    if(!option.value){
      logRequiredOptionsMissingError(option.key)
      process.exit(1)
      return
    }
  })
}
```

Given this array as options:

```
[{ branch: 'A15'},
 { awsKey: 'AKIAQ'},
 { awsSecret: '0ro'}]
```

I get undefined for `.value`.  And yes there's data there, I see it when I debug.

Basically I want it to go through and check whether each key has a value...otherwise log an error and stop if it comes across a key with no value

**UPDATE**

I ultimately went with this:

```
export function extractOptions(options){
  for (let option of options) {
    if(!option || option.length < 1){
      logRequiredOptionsMissingError(option[0][0])
      process.exit(1)
      return
    }
  }

  return options
}
```

As an added bonus I'll share my test

```
it('extracts options', () => {
      const options = [
        { branch: 'A15'},
        { awsKey: 'AKIAQ'},
        { awsSecret: '0ro'}
      ],
        list = Deploy.extractOptions(options)

      expect(list).to.deep.equal(options)
 })
```

Comment: The objects in the array don't have a value key. An object with a value prop, would look like this `{ value: 5 }`.

Comment: yea so maybe there's a better way to do this then.  I need to be able to work with name/value pairs, where names are unique.

Comment: Do you want to check if the objects are empty ? If you iterates the keys of each object, obviously they will have a value

Comment: yea and report on the name of the objects that are empty.  These are configuration options basically that I'll be using elsewhere in my code but I first have to run through and make sure whoever passes them are valid (they have values) and if not for now log out the names of the ones which don't

Comment: What do you mean by the name of the object ? Your objects doesn't have names... What do you mean by no value ? `{branch: ''}` the branch key has a value - an empty string. Can you be clearer ? Define names, valid, values,...

Comment: I want to print the property names if they do not have a value

Comment: @PositiveGuy What do you mean by no value ? undefined - empty string - null - 0 - false ?

Comment: no value means it cannot be any of those, its length has to be greater than 0..or in other words not empty

Comment: @PositiveGuy If your object has a key, it **has** a value. What length are you talking about ? An object doesn't have a length.

Comment: the length of the value

Comment: What if the value is null ? Or undefined ? I think that you misunderstood what an object is. Anyway you find a solution, good for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get key value pairs as array from object using `Object.entries()`

```
return options.map((option, i) => {
    var data = Object.entries(option)
    console.log(data[0][0], data[0][1]) // will be your key and value
    if(!data[0][1]){
      logRequiredOptionsMissingError(data[0][0])
      process.exit(1)
      return
    }
  })
```

**[Documentation on Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)**

Comment: weird, I get `Object.entries is not a function`

Comment: I came up with a hybrid approach, I'll update my post